# What happens when you re-run the Office365 Hybrid Configuration Wizard in an environment that is already setup?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-hybrid

Existing Infrastructure was an Exchange 2010 + Office365 Hybrid Configuration with all mailboxes hosted in Office365 which was configured months back.

If we run the Hybrid Configuration Wizard again within our environment, does it:

1. Erase the current configuration setup and start fresh
2. Pull in the Current Configuration for Review and editing?
3. or Other?

Basically how safe is it to re-run the Hybrid Configuration Wizard? Should it never be ran after the first time the environment is setup?

**Note:** 
To give an idea on why I am trying to run it again. 
Just recently installed a new Exchange 2016 server into the environment via powershell instead of the isntall GUI. Not sure if the Powershell method prevented some Hybrid configurations from applying. The old Exchange 2010 server is still active.

However even though the Exchange 2016 appears to be up and running correctly, it doesn't appear to have the same send/receive connector settings for communicating with Office365 that the old server has. So I was hoping running the Wizard on the new server, will check for that and make sure everything is actually running correct as opposed to looking like it is running correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Wizard won't blank everything, it should update the configuration to be how you want it to be.

Quoting the [Microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/hybrid-configuration-wizard):

> Based on the desired state, topology data, and current configuration, the Hybrid Configuration Engine establishes the "difference" between the on-premises Exchange and Exchange Online organizations and then executes configuration tasks to establish the desired state.

The connectors and some settings for the hybrid configuration are server-specific, and they won't automatically apply to the new server. At the very least, the tenant account will have to be updated to use the new server as the hybrid endpoint.

Here's a link on how to do the whole process of updating your hybrid server:
https://www.itpromentor.com/upgrade-hybrid-2016/

As I mentioned in my other answer, your Office 365 plan includes support, so you can also open up a case with them to get help changing your hybrid endpoint server.

Comment: I confirm, in the past I did a wizard re-run on a hybrid configuration to update one settings that was needed to be changed and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you could refer to the following article and check if you want to upgrade the hybrid server to Exchange 2016.
SHOULD YOU UPGRADE YOUR HYBRID EXCHANGE CONFIGURATION TO EXCHANGE 2016 OR NOT?
https://www.enowsoftware.com/solutions-engine/should-you-upgrade-your-hybrid-exchange-configuration-to-exchange-2016-or-not

If you decide to use Exchange 2016 as the hybrid server, you must re-run the HCW. The wizard gathers existing on-premises Exchange and Active Directory topology configuration data, Office 365 tenant and Exchange Online configuration data, defines several organization parameters, and then runs an extensive sequence of configuration tasks in both the on-premises and Exchange Online organizations.

Based on many users’ feedback, it is fine to re-run it if you have any configuration changed.